# Should I use the Underscore-compatible build of Lo-Dash when using it with BackboneJS?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, lodash

I noticed that Lo-Dash has a special Underscore-compatible build, ostensibly to address differences in function arguments/operations (since Lo-Dash is a superset of Underscore, I assume there are no Underscore functions missing from Lo-Dash).

I've also noticed that BackboneJS can be used with either Underscore or Lo-Dash.

My question: would it be unwise to use a "normal" build of Lo-Dash with BackboneJS? I can't find any indication of whether or not people are doing this in the wild, but it seems like a bad idea, especially if BackboneJS relies on functions that may be different in these builds. At the same time, it would be nice to use some of the newer functions in Lo-Dash, so I'd hate to miss out on those if it isn't necessary.

Comment: I am wondering the same thing. Lodash adds so many useful, 'simple' things like `_.isPlainObject()`. It might be worth asking on the lodash github issue tracker.

Answer (score 10):

*[edit]* From personal experience after using lodash for quite a while, I find that the differences are not too big a deal. I would suggest you DO use the normal build, but if you don't want to take any risk, go with the compat build.

---

To know the answer, see this wiki page, which summarizes the differences between the underscore Lo-Dash build and plain Lo-Dash:

https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/build-differences

#### Underscore build (includes the Backbone build which is a subset of the Underscore build)

- <del>Lo-Dash’s intuitive chaining is replaced with Underscore’s explicit chaining style</del> The `_.chain` method is still there if you want to use it.
- The `_.each` method does not exit early if the callback returns false
- The `_.defaults` and `_.extend` method iterate over inherited properties of source objects
- Extra features are removed from methods like `_.contains`, `_.omit`, `_.pick`, and `_.template`

Comment: So what's the answer? Does backbone.js work with a normal Lo-Dash build or not? I don't see how I'm supposed to deduce it from the information you've given here.

Comment: If you're using the normal lodash build, decide if you would be relying on the above mentioned functions or not. I would suggest you **DO** use the normal build, but if you don't want to take any risk, go with the compat build.

Answer (score 9):

I usually recommend trying Lo-Dash as is first. If you have issues you can drop back to the Underscore compat build. This goes for new projects or those already using Underscore and wanting to change.

You can also leverage the build utility and say create a version of Lo-Dash that uses the Underscore chaining style with something like `lodash -d plus=chain`.

Comment: It would be nice to know what exactly the differences are, as stated in another answers.

Comment: @DonaldTaylor there may be speed differences: http://jsperf.com/foreach-test-test/3

Comment: & the differences might be minor, [depending on the version you use](http://jsperf.com/foreach-test-test/4)

Answer (score 3):

I personally use require.js to load underscore/lodash. Therefore, in my app backbone doesn't know if it is underscore or lodash as long as I am passing "_" using AMD.

I started to use lodash just because, I read lodash has better performance. I am sure, you will find that if you google underscore vs lodash performance. So far, I haven't seen any missing functionality in lodash.

Anyways, I have the luxury to change it back to use Underscore with one line of code change in  the "Require" config file ...